# Bijective conformal map example

Tags: complex-analysis

How can i find an example of a

- Bijective conformal map between $$S= \{x+iy: 0 < x < 1, 0<y<1\}$$ onto $\mathfrak{H} = \{re^{i\theta}: 0<r<1, \ 0 <\theta<\pi\}$

I know conformal maps preserves angles.  Any insight of how to deal with such question would be helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately, such a map cannot be expressed by a simple formula. It will involve the inverse of an incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind. This integral is given explicitly in the Wikipedia article linked in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

These might help: [Conformal Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map#Complex_analysis), [Schwarz-Christoffel mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz%E2%80%93Christoffel_mapping#Example).

It says, a holomorphic $f:U\to\mathbb C$ function ($U\subseteq\mathbb C$ open subset), is *conformal*  iff $f'(z)\ne 0$ for $z\in U$. 
So, for example our favorit $z\mapsto e^z$ function is conformal, and so is $z\mapsto c\cdot z$ for any $c\ne 0$, and $z\mapsto 1/z$ if $0\notin U$.

Good, now consider $f_1:z\mapsto e^{\pi z}$, this maps $z=x+iy$ to the number with length $e^x$ and angle $\pi y$. It is getting closer what we want. (Where will $S$ go by $f_1$?)

So, before $f_1$ we should need a holomorphic function $f_0$ with nonvanishing differentiate that takes $S$ to a semi-infinite strip, preferaribly to $S':=\{x+iy \mid x<0,\ 0<y<1\}$. Then $f_1\circ f_0$ will be good.